# How to get value in the splitted string

Tags: vb.net

I have an example string which has been splitted using the symbol "\"

```
 Dim a As String = "123\456\7890\"
Dim leftString = a.Substring(0, msg.IndexOf("\"))
          TextBox1.Text = leftString
```

In textbox1 it show the number of "123" , and how can i get the number of "456" and "7890"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim a As String = "123\456\7890\"
Dim aSplit As String() = a.Split(New [Char]() {"\"c})
dim a1 as string = aSplit(0).Trim '123
dim a2 as string = aSplit(1).Trim '456
dim a3 as string = aSplit(2).Trim '7890
```

Comment: @taybriz..Thank you...this is what i want

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method, which gives you a string array.

```
Dim arr() As String = a.Split("\")
Console.WriteLine(arr(0)) ' 123
Console.WriteLine(arr(1)) ' 456
Console.WriteLine(arr(2)) ' 7890
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do a split onit you will get an array back that you can use:

```
Dim a As String = "123\456\7890\"
Dim leftString = a.split("\")
TextBox1.Text = leftString(0)

' 456 wouuld be in leftString(1) and 7890 in leftString(2)
```